Ensure Docker secrets are not exposed in container logs
I am addressing a particular issue. I have a script that the development team uses to set up the Docker stack, which includes creating a Docker secret and mounting it inside the container.
Solution :
I have created a custom docker plugin that ensures developers cannot exec into the container, preventing the manual reading of secrets. However, I am struggling to figure out how to prevent developers from accidentally printing or echoing the secret into log files.
Any suggestions are welcome..

This seems like a very general problem around credential handling.  Unless you're using some particularly involved security setup (say, a Vault client in the application getting a single-use password) the application will intrinsically have the credential in plain text at some point.  There's not a generic solution to ensure it's not logged or otherwise mishandled.  This can happen in any application in any framework in any language, and Docker can't really help with it at all.
